# Why/How can a revision graph like this be produced in perforce?

Tags: perforce

I have this revision graph from perforce and I am baffled how we managed to produce this graph. The part I find most puzzling is the part with the red square around it with revision 6 of row 2 being merged twice. The first time revision 6 is merged to revision 8 but with revision 11, I have never seen two revisions merged at the same time from separate branches. The second time revision 6 is merged like a normal merge but this file has been renamed for some time now so I don't know why the delete would suddenly get merged again. Can anyone explain the scenarios under which this can happen?

The top two rows are our trunk, the first row is our current trunk, the second row is the file before it was renamed, and the bottom row is a branch, we have many branches with the same strange merges in this branch.

[image: Revision Graph]

Comment: You have the same situation with 1 on the top row, right?

Comment: @TimRoberts the top two rows are our trunk, I added details about each row

Comment: Which revision specifically are you trying to explain the creation of?

Answer (score 1):

A lot depends on how revision #6 was created.  If you select revision 6, and open the "integrations" tab in the details pane, you can click on the source(s) of the integration(s) to reveal them in the graph.

A delete on top of a delete suggests that this file was re-added (under the old name) in some other branch, and then something unusual happened with that file that entailed the creation of an extra revision on the trunk for record-keeping purposes.  The relationship between that revision and revision #12 of the "new" file may be significant -- it looks like there are effectively 5 different file variants sharing 2 different names in this history graph, and maybe there are additional variants that we can't see here.

You may also be able to get some information by clicking on the specific revision you're curious about (#10 on the bottom?) and reading the changelist description.

In general, a `merge` operation will propagate whatever has happened in the source that has not yet happened in the target.  It does this by setting up a resolve, and in some cases the choices made during a resolve operation may negate some part of the changes made in the source and target (although the default option, where possible, will be to preserve and combine both).  So the final outcome of a merge depends on its inputs, and what happened during the resolve, and the inputs in turn may be influenced by merges from elsewhere (and resolve choices made as a consequence of those merges), and so on.

Note also that not every arrow you see in a revision graph is the result of a `merge` -- `copy` has its own semantics, and a forced integrate via `p4 integ -f` has its own as well.  (This is where reading the changelist description is useful -- hopefully the author of the change will have left some record there as to what their intent was and anything unusual they might have done, which can shortcut a lot of tedious forensic work.)

Comment: #6 when integrating to the bottom branch was an ignore but at revision #10 on the bottom row it is no longer ignored. This seems to be reproduced consistently in our other branches too

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference is between the "bottom branch" and the "bottom row" in your description -- having all the names obfuscated makes it extra hard to talk about the specific data.  I'd probably need to just see the raw filelogs to have a detailed explanation of what happened, since so much depends on data that I can't see at all in this picture.  This also might be a better question for support@perforce.com (or maybe forums.perforce.com) than StackOverflow.

Comment: Sorry bottom branch and bottom row are the same, I should have kept my terminology consistent. I will see if I can update my question with more information that is not as heavily obfuscated, not sure how my company feels about that.